# How to run a container (Postgres) via podman_container in CRIO?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ansible, podman

I want to rebuild the image from a running container after Ansible podman_container module with the CRIO runtime.

```
- name : run postgres container
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    name: "{{ minio_log_postgres_name }}"
    image: "{{ minio_log_postgres_image }}"
    state: present
    debug: yes
    recreate: yes
    detach: yes
    env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ minio_log_postgres_password }}"
```

When using the above task, podman shows that ("**Created**" in status)

**#podman ps -a**

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                          COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS      PORTS       NAMES
6ad9f017cd5e  docker.io/library/postgres:13  postgres    5 seconds ago  Created                 minio_log_postgres
```

it just created the image without running the container.

1. How do I make the container in running using podman_container?
2. How to get the return value from this task to consume in the following task, as I can't use 'register' for storing the results ?

Comment: Because of the typo(from POSTGRES_PASSOWRD TO POSTGRESS_PASSWORD), it has the issue to run a container. Still looking for the answer on the 2nd question.

Comment: Do you not want "state: started"? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/containers/podman/podman_container_module.html#parameter-state